# Post XML "Root Element Is Missing"

Tags: c#, xml

I keep getting the infamous 'Root element is missing' error when Posting XML data.  It sometimes works, but most times throws the error.

**C# Code:**

```
 public string postXMLData(string destinationUrl, string requestXml)
        {
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(destinationUrl);
            byte[] bytes;
            bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(requestXml);
            request.ContentType = "text/xml; encoding='utf-8'";
            request.ContentLength = bytes.Length;
            request.Method = "POST";
            Stream requestStream = request.GetRequestStream();
            requestStream.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
            requestStream.Close();
            HttpWebResponse response;
            response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                string responseStr = new StreamReader(responseStream).ReadToEnd();
                return responseStr;
            }
            return "";
        }
```

**XML Data:**

```
<Person>
    <idPeople>0</idPeople>
    <AccountNumber>TEST02H</AccountNumber>
    <cFirstName>TEST 2</cFirstName>
    <cLastName>TEST 2</cLastName>
    <cTelWork/>
    <cTelMobile>0713473835</cTelMobile>
    <cEmail>myemail@mydomain.com</cEmail>
    <ubPPLIsActive>true</ubPPLIsActive>
    <ubPPLSMSOptIn>true</ubPPLSMSOptIn>
    <udPPLSMSOptInActivateDate>30/05/2017</udPPLSMSOptInActivateDate>
    <ulPPLAccessType>Administrator</ulPPLAccessType>
    <ubPPLNewsletterSignUp>true</ubPPLNewsletterSignUp>
    <ubPPLIncludeBuyerEmails>true</ubPPLIncludeBuyerEmails>
</Person>
```

Comment: So where is the error coming? Have you looked using WireShark or Fiddler to see if the XML *is* actually being sent?

Comment: @JonSkeet The XML is not being sent as it breaks somewhere in the Post method.

Comment: Xml expects no space before first open angle bracket.  You have some error. Saw same error last week.  It turned out HttpResponse was gzip and had to unzip.

Comment: Well, I'd sooner trust the diagnostics of looking at the request itself in a network viewer - have you done that? Have you validated that `requestXml` and `bytes` are okay? (It's not clear why you're using `Encoding.ASCII` rather than `Encoding.UTF8` btw...)

Comment: @jdweng: XML is generally fine with whitespace before the start of a document. (See https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/) There's also no indication that I can see that there *is* a space before the first open angle bracket - why are you guessing that there is?

Comment: @jdweng: Failing to decompress a response sounds entirely different to "there's some extra text at the start of a document".

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm not sure how to validate the bytes?   the requestXML is ok as I'm constructing it in code and have double checked it.   Also changed to 'Encoding.UTF8'  but still getting same result.

Comment: And have you used a network analyzer to look at the request yet?

Comment: I don't have a Network Analyzer :(

Comment: What is the destination? Could this be the response that is incorrect and not your request? You can download WireShark or Fiddler to investigate further.

Comment: @Scrobi The desitnation Url works fine sometimes...it was working before. just started throwing this error recently. I will give WireShark a try

Comment: Still battling with this :( have tried everything..

Comment: @JonSkeet My destination URL has a query string in it, would that be causing the issue?

Comment: I wouldn't think so, but have you looked at what's being sent on the wire yet?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm downloading WireShark now and will investigate. will let you know what I find asap

Comment: @JonSkeet After downloading WireShark and trying to check my network traffic, it unfortunately did not show me anything. I'm using a 3G modem, so not sure if that is the reason. Is there any other way I can write this code to send the XML string to the server?

Comment: @Orion: I would work on the diagnosis before trying random cures. Do you *have* to use a 3G modem? Are you able to try Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) instead of Wireshark?

Comment: @JonSkeet I only have a 3G modem connection. Going to try Fiddler now..

Comment: @JonSkeet I've got Fiddler going and now trying to figure out what to look for.  Can I post updates to my Question with some of the data, if you would be able to look at it and tell me more?

Comment: Yes, you should absolutely edit your question to show more diagnostics. Basically, you should be looking at the request: headers and body.

Comment: @JonSkeet, ok cool, let me try and figure the Fiddler interface out more. I'm not seeing the link it's supposed to be posting to, so need to find out more. Will update question accordingly.

Comment: @JonSkeet after going through the code again. I took the link that i'm posting to and entered into the address bar. It turns out the application I'm posting to has an error :/  hence the 'root element is missing' error. Thank you for all your comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue for me was in 2 places.

1. The application I am posting to had an error, which I resolved. I found this error by pasting the destination URL into my browser to see what happens.
2. I needed to System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode the XML.

I used this method for posting in the end.

```
WebClient client = new WebClient();
string xmlResult = client.DownloadString(_workContext.AccountingWebServiceLink + "?action=updatesecondary&xml=" + System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(strXML));
```